# Como executar uma INSERT procedure com o campo GETDATE? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, data, get, stored-procedures

Seguinte, eu criei uma procedure que possui dois parâmetros Dt_Inclusao e Dt_Alteracao, gostaria de saber como faço para inserir(ou se é possível utilizar) um **getdate** para pegar a data atual, ao invés de ter que sempre digitar manualmente a como por exemplo('2020-05-07')

Abaixo está o execute da procedure.

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_CRUDLogin]

    @ID = 10,
    @Usuario = N'Teste',
    @Senha = N'123456',
    @Nome = N'Teste',
    @Email = N'teste@gmail.com',
    @Telefone = N'8002-4922',
    @Dt_inclusao =  '2020-05-07' <-- esse campo gostaria de utilizar um GETDATE no lugar da data especificada.
    @Dt_alteracao = NULL,
    @StatementType = N'Insert'
```

Minha procedure :
`ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CRUDLogin]
(
@ID integer,
@Usuario varchar(60),
@Senha varchar(60),
@Nome varchar(60),
@Email varchar(60),
@Telefone varchar(15),
@Dt_inclusao datetime,
@Dt_alteracao datetime,
@StatementType nvarchar(20)='')
AS
    BEGIN
        IF @StatementType='Insert'
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO TbCADLogin
                            (ID,
                             Usuario,
                             Senha,
                             Nome,
                             Email,
                             Telefone,
                             Dt_inclusao,
                             Dt_alteracao)
                VALUES      (@ID,
                             @Usuario,
                             @Senha,
                             @Nome,
                             @Email,
                             @Telefone,
                             @Dt_inclusao,
                             @Dt_alteracao)
END
    IF @StatementType='Select'
        BEGIN
            SELECT *
            FROM TbCADLogin
END
    IF @StatementType = 'Update'
        BEGIN
            UPDATE TbCADLogin
            SET Usuario = @Usuario,
                Senha = @Senha,
                Nome = @Nome,
                Email = @Email,
                Telefone = @Telefone,
                Dt_inclusao = @Dt_inclusao,
                Dt_alteracao = @Dt_alteracao
            WHERE ID = @ID
END
    ELSE IF @StatementType='Delete'
        begin
            delete from TbCADLogin
            where ID = @ID
        END
END`

Tentativa de execute com o GETDATE:

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_CRUDLogin]

        @ID = 10,
        @Usuario = N'Teste',
        @Senha = N'123456',
        @Nome = N'Teste',
        @Email = N'teste@gmail.com',
        @Telefone = N'8002-4922',
        @Dt_inclusao =  GETDATE, <--- GETDATE definido em vez do '2020-05-07'
        @Dt_alteracao = NULL,
        @StatementType = N'Insert'
```

Ao tentar utilizar o GETDATE recebo o seguinte resultado

```
"Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure dbo.sp_CRUDLogin, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 0]
    Erro ao converter tipo de dados nvarchar em date.

    Completion time: 2020-05-07T15:22:07.2551684-03:00"
```

O que devo fazer para que esta procedure funcione, de modo que, com apenas o GETDATE eu consiga a data e hora atual ao utilizar o insert?

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, coloquei no lugar do Dt_inclusão na procedure o GETDATE dessa forma

```
BEGIN
                INSERT INTO TbCADLogin
                            (ID,
                             Usuario,
                             Senha,
                             Nome,
                             Email,
                             Telefone,
                             Dt_inclusao,
                             Dt_alteracao)
                VALUES        (@ID,
                             @Usuario,
                             @Senha,
                             @Nome,
                             @Email,
                             @Telefone,
                             GETDATE(),
                             @Dt_alteracao)
```

E pode fazer da mesma forma no UPDATE:

```
UPDATE TbCADLogin
        SET    Usuario = @Usuario,
            Senha = @Senha,
            Nome = @Nome,
            Email = @Email,
            Telefone = @Telefone,
            Dt_inclusao = GETDATE(),
            Dt_alteracao = @Dt_alteracao
        WHERE ID = @ID
```

Ao executar a procedure só deixar o campo Dt_inclusao em branco:

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_CRUDLogin]
        @ID = 12,
        @Usuario = N'Riptde',
        @Senha = N'123456',
        @Nome = N'Ronnan',
        @Email = N'ronnan@abc.com.br',
        @Telefone = N'212354632',
        @Dt_inclusao = N'',
        @Dt_alteracao = NULL,
        @StatementType = N'Insert'
```

Com isso, deu certo :)